# Full Sceen show text A , mobile screen show text B

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to do that?
If full screen then show "FULL SCREEN MEMBERSHIP"
If mobile or tablet size then show "Please use Full Screen" and hide textA
Thanks !!!

```css
 @media only screen and (min-width: 301px) {
html,body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #356aa0;
}
.fullScreen{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;

}
p {
display:none
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
    
  }
  p {
display:block
}
}
```

```html
<div class="fullScreen">
FULL SCREEN MEMBERSHIP
    </div>
 
 

 <p id="mobile">Please use Full Screen</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #356aa0;
}

.fullScreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  display: none
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  p {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .fullScreen{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fullScreen">
  FULL SCREEN MEMBERSHIP
</div>



<p id="mobile">Please use Full Screen</p>
```

Comment: So you just remove @media only screen and (min-width: 301px) , first line. That works 100%!! Thanks